# How to convert list of IDs formatted in varchar into int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in SQL Server converting list of IDs as `varchar` into integer to be used as parameter. I know that it will work if you do it like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyTableId IN (26,27,28)` --list of IDs to be selected
```

but putting this list of IDs in `varchar` since I wanted my parameters to be dynamic, returns some error.
My code goes this way:

```
DECLARE @ids varchar(100)
SET @ids = '26,27,28'

SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyTableId in (@ids)  --(26,27,28)`
```

It doesn't work because the `MyTableId` is datatype `int`

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Because "since i wanted my parameters to be dynamic" isn't making much sense without a context.

Comment: This is not called "dynamic".  This is called "a hack".

Comment: Which dmbs? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to conver the the comma seperated value to table. Do this for SQL SERVER

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END


SELECT * FROM MyTable where MyTableId in 
      (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString('26,27,28', ','))  --(26,27,28)
```